# Newbie, Value Error in extracting images from website using webscraping

Tags: python, image, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to run this code but it is giving Value Error:

> ValueError: unknown url type: '/images/christmas-getaway-2017.jpg'

Please go through this code:

```
    import requests
    import urllib.request
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    from html.parser import HTMLParser
    url = 'https://yts.movie/search/all/all/all/latest/'
    response = requests.get(url)
    response
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    print(soup.prettify())
    frame = soup.findAll('div',{'class':'browse-movie-wrap col-xs-10 col-sm-5'})
    for frame in frame:
        figure = frame.find('figure')
        photo_url = figure.img['src']
        print(photo_url)
        name = photo_url.split('/')
        name = name[-1]
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(photo_url, name)
```

Answer (score 0):

That photo url is the relative url :

```
src="/images/christmas-getaway-2017.jpg"
```

Its not a complete url with no http/https , so that why its a value error ,

```
https://yts.movie/images/christmas-getaway-2017.jpg
```

Base url : https://yts.movie/images/ 
This is the correct url for the image so define your base url first and then extract the name , of the image the way you are extracting is fine. and concatenate with the base url

Comment: But the code is extracting only the relative URl from the website. I have not saved manually. It may be the HTML error of the website that it is showin

Comment: yeah, if  the URL is on the same server relative URL works for the website but when you are trying to get ti outside from the hosting server you need the exact location